# Netty reference counting for temporary buffer

Tags: java, netty

I have code that looks something like this:

```
ByteBuf payload = Unpooled.buffer();
payload.writeByte(...);
...

ByteBuf fullMessage = Unpooled.buffer();
fullMessage.writeByte(...); // header
fullMessage.writeBytes(payload);

channel.writeAndFlush(fullMessage);
```

As far as I understand I would need two try catch blocks in this case, correct? Is there any better way?

Comment: And why 1 try-catch is not enough?

Comment: Do you mean create buffer first? It's a bad practice to declare variable before I need it. Also, the code is somewhat more complicated than this. I just provided shortened example to illustrate the structure.